# 400 Bad Request http call angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Hello I'm trying to access this url to get the token of my application but all the time gives me a 400, the proxy conf of my application is as follows.

proxy.conf:

```
"/token": {
      "target": {
          "host": "url",
          "protocol": "https",
          "port": 443
      },
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel":"info",
      "pathRewrite": {
          "^/token": "/auth/token"
      }
  }
```

And this is the function to retrieve the token:

```
private getAccessToken(): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    const url = '/token';
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('client_id', 'daiga6')
      .set('client_secret', 'aouwhyruhg8ag')
      .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

    const headers = new Headers({
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
      Accept: '*/*',
      'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
      Pragma: 'no-cache',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });
    const options: any = {headers};
    return this.http.post(url, body, options);
  }
```

The error message that returns my call is as follows:

Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

Any ideas?

With this configuration you solve it:

```
"/token": {
      "target": {
          "host": "url",
          "protocol": "https:",
          "port": 443
      },
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel":"info",
      "pathRewrite": {
          "^/token": "/auth/token"
      }
  }
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Use `https`.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I tried to change the compilation so that the application started on https instead of http and the error persists.